# How can I rename this table?

Tags: db2, rename

I Have a problem. I created a table using this :

```
CREATE TABLE MHS_KOTA2_1028( 
NIM VARCHAR(15)PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL REFERENCES MAHASISWA_1028(NIM),
K_KOTA VARCHAR(9),
K_PROPINSI VARCHAR(9),
K_NEGARA VARCHAR(9),
FOREIGN KEY(K_KOTA,K_NEGARA,K_PROPINSI) REFERENCES
M_KOTA_1028(K_KOTA,K_NEGARA,K_PROPINSI), ALAMAT VARCHAR(100),KODE_POS VARCHAR(9));
```

when i rename the table using\

```
RENAME MHS_KOTA2_1028 TO MHS_KOTA_1028;
```

there was an error like this.

> The source table cannot be renamed because it is referenced in a view,
>   materialized query table, trigger, SQL function, SQL method, check
>   constraint, referential constraint, or XSR object.. SQLCODE=-750,
>   SQLSTATE=42986, DRIVER=4.13.111

I try searching for its solution and i didn't get it. So how can we fix this?

Answer (score 1):

The error tells you what to do.

> The source table cannot be renamed because it is referenced in a view, materialized query table, trigger, SQL function, SQL method, check constraint, referential constraint, or XSR object.. SQLCODE=-750, SQLSTATE=42986, DRIVER=4.13.111

You have to check all of your views and tables for a reference to MHS_KOTA2_1028.  If you find any, you have to first delete the views and / or tables with the reference, then do your rename, then add them back.